# Retrieving an image in Google Sheet cell using Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client, imagedownload

I am unable to read in an image in a Google Sheet cell despite using the Sheets API v4, as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489282/how-to-retrieve-images-in-cell-using-google-sheet-api). The value I get is simply a null string, `""`. However, I am able to retrieve all text data in other cells.

Any advice is much appreciated.

I adapted the example [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) with the necessary changes such as using my `spreadsheetId`, sheet name, and the appropriate range.

```
spreadsheetId = 'XXXXX'
rangeName = 'Sheet1!A1:C1'
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

Looking into `values`, I get the text in A1 and C1. B1, in the Google Sheet UI, contains `"=image('https://.......')"`.  But when I look at the corresponding index in `values`, I see only a null string.

Comment: Hi and welcome on Stack Overflow. Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Jacques,  Thanks for your reply.  Edited with more information.  Hopefully, good enough.

Comment: Note that you are using `spreadsheet.values.get` and the referenced question uses `spreadsheets.get`, which allows retrieving the **formula**s.