# Google Sheet Script to Insert > Image > Image in Cell > By URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have my google sheets sheet where I use the new formula =IMAGE()
This formula works like 90% of the time, and the other 10% it doesn't show the image.
The images are perfectly fine the problem is with this formula.

I tried manually without a macro to use **Image > Image in Cell > By URL** and it works perfectly fine.
I want to create a macro or script that insert an image in cell, at the moment insert it in active cell selected.
The url is located also in active cell.

Help anyone please?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I recommend you to read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/spreadsheetapp#insert-image-in-a-spreadsheet). Also, take this opportunity to learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56140419

Comment: Jescanellas I will go over it again, but i'm coming here after long reading, being stuck, and not knowing what to do. Yet my question is still posted with a lot of info both title and body, and even image. Sorry either way. @TheMaster I've read it prior to posting my question, I used their code but it adds image not inside a cell as I want

Comment: @Kobe2424 I added the link for you to read it. It clearly states it can't be done. If you know how to write a script, I'd suggest using the `=image()` and then  record a macro of copy>paste values only to remove the formula and keep the image. Thus it won't heave to load every time.

Comment: @Kobe2424 Added a answer using the workaround. See duplicate answer linked above.