# Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getContentUrl on object SpreadsheetApp.CellImage

Tags: javascript, image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to extract an in-cell-image from google sheets to later paste to a google docs. Using this method I'm getting an error and couldn't find any documentation about this.

```
function onClick(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = app.getActive().getSheetByName('FILE');
  var image = sheet.getRange('D4').getValue();
  var url = image.getContentUrl()
  Logger.log(url)
}
```

> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getContentUrl on object SpreadsheetApp.CellImage

I've also tried using this method using [DocsServiceApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp)->

```
DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(spreadsheetId)
  .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  .getImages();
```

But this led to a different error:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com returned code 403. Truncated server response: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "exportSizeLimitExceeded",
    "message": "This file is too large to be expo... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
    at gToM(SpreadsheetAppp:171:25)
    at getImages(SpreadsheetAppp:34:14)
```

Does anyone know how to fix one of these errors, or a different method for extracting the images from a google sheet?

Comment: Note: This was closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138090/how-to-get-an-image-in-cell-url-from-the-google-sheets-api This is reopened as it seemed it isn't a exact duplicate. But the original duplicate might still help and maybe closed again by the community as it sees fit.

Comment: First, I apologize that my Google Apps Script library was not useful for your situation. From the error message of `"reason": "exportSizeLimitExceeded"`, I'm worried that the image size might be large. So, I would like to confirm your situation. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue of `"reason": "exportSizeLimitExceeded"`?

Comment: If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you very much for the library you built. It is brilliant. But yes, as you mentioned, I have many images in that spreadsheet, and they are of relatively high resolution. If there was a way to extract just specific images, and not all of them at once I'm pretty sure that would resolve it. But the library doesn't support this at present time if I understand correctly? Thanks again for helping out!